# How to write query with like in Doctrine2

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, sql-like

I want to write this statement with Doctrine's Query Builder:

```
WHERE e.date LIKE '%$month'
```

(I want the selected date to end with the value of the variable $month)

e.date is of type date and has values like this: '05/05/2013'

$month variable will be a string with value like this: '05/2013'

So I want to take all items for month 05/2013 with my query

Here is my whole function:

```
public function findForMonthAndCat($user, $month, $category)
{
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->where('e.date LIKE :month') //I don't know how to write this line
        ->andWhere('e.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('e.category = :category')
        ->setParameter('date', $month)
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->setParameter('category', $category)
         ->getQuery();

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

I tried this:

```
->where($q->expr()->like('e.category', '%:month')
```

but it says that I'm calling expr() on a non-object.

I tried this:

```
public function findExpensesForMonthAndCat($user, $month, $category)
{
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->where('e.date LIKE :month')
        ->andWhere('e.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('e.category = :category')
        ->setParameter('date', '%'.$month)
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->setParameter('category', $category)
         ->getQuery();

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

but it says 
`Invalid parameter: token date is not defined in the query.`

Can you help me please? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace date by 'month', that's the name of your parameter :

```
public function findForMonthAndCat($user, $month, $category)
{
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->where('e.date LIKE :month')
        ->andWhere('e.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('e.category = :category')
        ->setParameter('month', "%$month")
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->setParameter('category', $category)
         ->getQuery();

    return $q->getResult();
}
```